# how to log size of array with ilog

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this code and just want to log size of array :

```
auto owner = abi_data["owner"].as<chain::authority>();
auto arrSize = std::size(owner.keys);
ilog(arrSize);
```

But have an error :

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'fc::log_message'
```

How can i fix it?

I understand that the c ++ methodology is very specific. Therefore, I will expand my question and thus grope the way.

how to get public key string from `auto owner`.

i tried :

```
   std::string k = owner.keys[0].key
   error: no viable conversion from 'eosio::chain::public_key_type' (aka 'fc::crypto::public_key') to 'std::string'
```

I don’t understand how I should transform all this for correct work and get correct public key and replace hardcoded `old_account_name` .

full code :

```
else if (action.name == N(newaccount)) {

               auto new_account_name = abi_data["newact"].as<chain::name>().to_string();
               auto creator = abi_data["creator"].as<chain::name>().to_string();
               std::string old_account_name = "EOS7ea3Dj15nUkKz3diU7BmE5FV5aNKsBKL6WScwEaKzNwDp41SSU";
               auto owner = abi_data["owner"].as<chain::authority>();
               auto active = abi_data["active"].as<chain::authority>();
               ilog("new_account_name: " + new_account_name + " ,creator: " + creator);

               *m_session << "UPDATE user_address SET address = :nan WHERE crypto_currency_asset_id = :ai AND address = :oan",
                  soci::use(new_account_name, "nan"),
                  soci::use(old_account_name, "oan"),
                  soci::use(asset_id, "ai");
            }
```

Comment: I don't know what `ilog` is, but I'd suspect you should convert your integer [`to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: needs full context on the code, especially what `ilog()` is meant to be, and I suspect there is more to that error that you didn't include also, i.e. a list of candidate constructors.

Comment: updated body of question

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

```
auto arrSize = sizeof(owner.keys)/sizeof(owner.keys[0]);
auto ownerPK = static_cast<std::string>(owner.keys[0].key);
```